# How to get notified that the share operation has completed

Tags: c#, windows-8

I am building an Windows 8 app. I am using the share charm to let users share data. I want to get notified that the user completed the share operation. I have tried with

```
    private static void ShareTextHandler(DataTransferManager sender, DataRequestedEventArgs e)
    {
      ..........
        request.Data.OperationCompleted += Data_OperationCompleted;
        request.Data.Destroyed += Data_Destroyed;
      ..........
    }
```

But the two event handlers never get triggered. Is there a proper way to find out the user has finished sharing content (The charms bar has collapsed after the share operation finished)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So far the only solution ( a hacky one) is to register to the page GotFocus event and have a flag that represents a share operation has started. The gotfocus event handler

```
    void ListViewPage_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (App.startedSharing)
            App.UnRegisterForShare();
    }
```

That is why i wanted to know the share has ended, so i can unregister the DataRequested handler like this

```
    public static void UnRegisterForShare()
    {
        startedSharing = false;
        DataTransferManager dataTransferManager = DataTransferManager.GetForCurrentView();
        dataTransferManager.DataRequested -= ShareTextHandler;
    }
```

Comment: Did you ever find a better solution to this?

Comment: Nope.. so far this is the only solution i found

Comment: Ok, thanks. In my case I need to understand if a share (email especially) has been made in the share charm, but I cannot find any solution for this.